# 'xsl:value-of' in XSLT doesnt work properly. It inserts value for few and does not for other fields

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML which i want to transform using XSLT. I wrote down my XSLT to pick a particular XML element (Unique key) and append it to various different child nodes so that when inserted into an MS Access, they all stay connected. Interesting part is the logic to retrieve the unique key say `<ReferenceNumber>` in `<Header>` is getting inserted into few XML child's but not all of them. 
Below is the XML

```
<PreciseIDServer>
<PIDXMLVersion>xcxc</PIDXMLVersion>
<SessionID>xc.xcx</SessionID>
<Header>
    <ReportDate>xc</ReportDate>
    <ReportTime>xcx</ReportTime>
    <ProductOption>cx</ProductOption>
    <Subcode>xcxc</Subcode>
    <ReferenceNumber>xcx</ReferenceNumber>
</Header>
<Summary>
    <TransactionID>xcx</TransactionID>
    <InitialDecision>xcx</InitialDecision>
    <FinalDecision>xc</FinalDecision>
    <CrossReferenceIndicatorsGrid>
        <FullNameVerifiesToAddress code="MA"/>
        <FullNameVerifiesToSSN code="MA"/>
        <FullNameVerifiesToDL code="NM"/>
        <FullNameVerifiesToPhone code="NM"/>
        <SurnameOnlyVerifiesToAddress code="NM"/>
        <SurnameOnlyVerifiesToSSN code="NM"/>
        <SurnameOnlyVerifiesToDL code="NM"/>
        <SurnameOnlyVerifiesToPhone code="NM"/>
        <AddressVerifiesToFullName code="MA"/>
        <AddressVerifiesToSurnameOnly code="NM"/>
        <AddressVerifiesToSSN code="MA"/>
        <AddressVerifiesToDL code="NM"/>
        <AddressVerifiesToPhone code="NM"/>
        <SSNVerifiesToFullName code="MA"/>
        <SSNVerifiesToSurnameOnly code="NM"/>
        <SSNVerifiesToAddress code="MA"/>
        <DLVerifiesToFullName code="NM"/>
        <DLVerifiesToSurnameOnly code="NM"/>
        <DLVerifiesToAddress code="NM"/>
        <PhoneVerifiesToFullName code="NM"/>
        <PhoneVerifiesToSurnameOnly code="NM"/>
        <PhoneVerifiesToAddress code="NM"/>
    </CrossReferenceIndicatorsGrid>
    <DateOfBirthMatch code="9"/>
</Summary>
<GLBDetail>
    <FraudShield>
        <Indicator code="01">N</Indicator>
        <Indicator code="02">N</Indicator>
        <Indicator code="03">N</Indicator>
        <Indicator code="04">N</Indicator>
        <Indicator code="05">N</Indicator>
        <Indicator code="06">N</Indicator>
        <Indicator code="10">N</Indicator>
        <Indicator code="11">N</Indicator>
        <Indicator code="13">N</Indicator>
        <Indicator code="14">N</Indicator>
        <Indicator code="15">N</Indicator>
        <Indicator code="16">N</Indicator>
        <Indicator code="17">N</Indicator>
        <Indicator code="18">N</Indicator>
        <Indicator code="21">N</Indicator>
        <Indicator code="25">N</Indicator>
        <Indicator code="26">N</Indicator>
    </FraudShield>
</GLBDetail>
<PreciseMatch>
    <Version>zx.zx</Version>
    <ResponseStatusCode code="00"/>
    <PreciseMatchTransactionID>zx-zx-zx-xz</PreciseMatchTransactionID>
    <PreciseMatchScore>zx</PreciseMatchScore>
    <PreciseMatchDecision code=" "/>
    <Addresses>
            <Address>
                <Summary>
                    <VerificationResult code="A1"/>
                    <Type code="S "/>
                    <UnitMismatchResult code="  "/>
                    <HighRiskResult code="N "/>
                    <Counts>
                        <StandardizedAddressReturnCount>xz</StandardizedAddressReturnCount>
                        <ResidentialAddressMatchCount>zx</ResidentialAddressMatchCount>
                        <ResidentialAddressReturnCount>zx</ResidentialAddressReturnCount>
                        <HighRiskAddressReturnCount>zx</HighRiskAddressReturnCount>
                        <BusinessAddressMatchCount>zx</BusinessAddressMatchCount>
                        <BusinessAddressReturnCount>zx</BusinessAddressReturnCount>
                    </Counts>
                </Summary>
                <Detail>
                    <StandardizedAddressRcd>
                        <Surname>xc</Surname>
                        <FirstName>xc</FirstName>
                        <Middle>cx</Middle>
                        <Address>cx xc xc</Address>
                        <City>xc</City>
                        <State>xc</State>
                        <ZipCode>xc</ZipCode>
                        <ZipPlus4>xc</ZipPlus4>
                    </StandardizedAddressRcd>
                    <ResidentialAddressRcd>
                        <Surname>xc</Surname>
                        <FirstName>xc</FirstName>
                        <Address>xc xc xc</Address>
                        <City>xc</City>
                        <State>xc</State>
                        <ZipCode>xc</ZipCode>
                        <ZipPlus4>xc</ZipPlus4>
                    </ResidentialAddressRcd>
                    <ResidentialAddressRcd>
                        <Surname>xc</Surname>
                        <FirstName>xc</FirstName>
                        <Middle>xc</Middle>
                        <Address>xc xc xc</Address>
                        <City>xc</City>
                        <State>xc</State>
                        <ZipCode>c</ZipCode>
                        <ZipPlus4>xc</ZipPlus4>
                        <AreaCode>xc</AreaCode>
                        <Phone>xc</Phone>
                        <OtherHouseholdMembers>
                        <Name>xc zx</Name>
                        <Name>zx</Name>
                        </OtherHouseholdMembers>
                        <MonthsAtResidence>xc</MonthsAtResidence>
                        <LastUpdatedDate>xc</LastUpdatedDate>
                    </ResidentialAddressRcd>
                    <ResidentialAddressRcd>
                        <Surname>zx</Surname>
                        <FirstName>zx</FirstName>
                        <Address>zx zx zx</Address>
                        <City>zx</City>
                        <State>zx</State>
                        <ZipCode>zx</ZipCode>
                        <ZipPlus4>zx</ZipPlus4>
                    </ResidentialAddressRcd>
                    <ResidentialAddressRcd>
                        <Surname>zx</Surname>
                        <FirstName>zx</FirstName>
                        <Middle>zx</Middle>
                        <Address>zx zx zx</Address>
                        <City>zx</City>
                        <State>zx</State>
                        <ZipCode>zx</ZipCode>
                        <ZipPlus4>zx</ZipPlus4>
                    </ResidentialAddressRcd>
                    <HighRiskAddressRcd>
                        <BusinessName>zx zx zx</BusinessName>
                        <Address>zx zx zx</Address>
                        <City>zx</City>
                        <State>zx</State>
                        <ZipCode>zx</ZipCode>
                        <ZipPlus4>zx</ZipPlus4>
                        <AreaCode>zx</AreaCode>
                        <Phone>zx</Phone>
                    </HighRiskAddressRcd>
                    <HighRiskAddressDescription>
                        <HighRiskDescription>zx &amp; zx</HighRiskDescription>
                    </HighRiskAddressDescription>
                </Detail>
            </Address>
    </Addresses>
    <Phones>
        <Phone>
            <Summary>
                <VerificationResult code="MX"/>
                <Classification code="X"/>
                <HighRiskResult code="N"/>
                <Counts>
                    <ResidentialPhoneMatchCount>zx</ResidentialPhoneMatchCount>
                    <ResidentialPhoneReturnCount>zx</ResidentialPhoneReturnCount>
                    <HighRiskPhoneReturnCount>zx</HighRiskPhoneReturnCount>
                    <BusinessPhoneMatchCount>zx</BusinessPhoneMatchCount>
                    <BusinessPhoneReturnCount>zx</BusinessPhoneReturnCount>
                </Counts>
            </Summary>
            <Detail>
                <HighRiskPhoneDescription>
                    <HighRiskDescription>zx zx zx zx zx zx/zx</HighRiskDescription>
                </HighRiskPhoneDescription>
            </Detail>
        </Phone>
    </Phones>
    <ConsumerID>
        <Summary>
            <VerificationResult code="YA"/>
            <DeceasedResult code="N"/>
            <FormatResult code="V"/>
            <IssueResult code="I"/>
            <IssueState>zx</IssueState>
            <IssueStartRange>zx</IssueStartRange>
            <IssueEndRange>zx</IssueEndRange>
            <Counts>
                <ConsumerIDReturnCount>zx</ConsumerIDReturnCount>
            </Counts>
        </Summary>
        <Detail>
            <ConsumerIDRcd>
                <Surname>zx</Surname>
                <FirstName>zx</FirstName>
                <Address>zx zx zx</Address>
                <City>x</City>
                <State>zx</State>
                <ZipCode>zx</ZipCode>
                <ZipPlus4>zx</ZipPlus4>
                <ReportedDate>zx</ReportedDate>
                <LastUpdatedDate>zx</LastUpdatedDate>
            </ConsumerIDRcd>
        </Detail>
    </ConsumerID>
    <DateOfBirth>
        <Summary>
            <MatchResult code="9"/>
            <MonthOfBirth>xz</MonthOfBirth>
            <DayOfBirth>zx</DayOfBirth>
            <YearOfBirth>zx</YearOfBirth>
        </Summary>
    </DateOfBirth>
    <DriverLicense/>
    <ChangeOfAddresses>
        <ChangeOfAddress>
            <Summary>
                <VerificationResult code="C "/>
                <Counts>
                    <ChangeOfAddressReturnCount>zx</ChangeOfAddressReturnCount>
                </Counts>
            </Summary>
            <Detail>
                <ChangeOfAddressRcd>
                    <Name>zx zx zx</Name>
                    <Address>zx zx zx</Address>
                    <City>zx</City>
                    <State>zx</State>
                    <ZipCode>zx</ZipCode>
                    <ZipPlus4>zx</ZipPlus4>
                </ChangeOfAddressRcd>
            </Detail>
        </ChangeOfAddress>
    </ChangeOfAddresses>
    <OFAC>
        <Summary>
            <VerificationResult code="1 "/>
            <Counts>
                <OFACReturnCount>zx</OFACReturnCount>
            </Counts>
        </Summary>
    </OFAC>
    <PreviousAddresses>
        <PreviousAddress>
            <Summary>
                <Counts>
                    <PreviousAddressReturnCount>zx</PreviousAddressReturnCount>
                </Counts>
            </Summary>
            <Detail>
                <PreviousAddressRcd>
                    <Address>zx xz xz</Address>
                    <City>zx</City>
                    <State>zx</State>
                    <ZipCode>zx</ZipCode>
                    <ZipPlus4>zx</ZipPlus4>
                    <ReportedDate>zx</ReportedDate>
                    <LastUpdatedDate>zx</LastUpdatedDate>
                </PreviousAddressRcd>
                <PreviousAddressRcd>
                    <Address>zx 2 zx zx</Address>
                    <City>zx</City>
                    <State>zx</State>
                    <ZipCode>zx</ZipCode>
                    <ReportedDate>zx</ReportedDate>
                    <LastUpdatedDate>zx</LastUpdatedDate>
                </PreviousAddressRcd>
            </Detail>
        </PreviousAddress>
    </PreviousAddresses>
    <SSNFinder>
        <Summary>
            <Counts>
                <SSNFinderReturnCount>zx</SSNFinderReturnCount>
            </Counts>
        </Summary>
    </SSNFinder>
</PreciseMatch>
```

and this is the sample xslt i wrote

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!--   <xsl:param name="refn" select="11"/> -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <dataroot>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </dataroot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Adding ReferenceNumber tag to ChangeOfAddressRcd -->
<xsl:template match="ChangeOfAddressRcd"> 
     <ChangeOfAddressRcd>
        <ReferenceNumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../../../../Header/ReferenceNumber"/>
        </ReferenceNumber>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </ChangeOfAddressRcd>                      
</xsl:template>

<!-- Adding ReferenceNumber tag to ConsumerIDRcd -->
<xsl:template match="ConsumerIDRcd"> 
    <ConsumerIDRcd>
        <ReferenceNumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../../../../Header/ReferenceNumber"/>
        </ReferenceNumber>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </ConsumerIDRcd>                      
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works and inserts reference number for the `<ChangeOfAddressRcd>` Node but inserting blank reference number for `<ConsumerIDRcd>` Node. Its the same logic and everything but it wont insert here for some reason. Any help is appreciated. Been stuck on this for more than a week now, googled every where but did not have much luck. Thanks

Comment: Well, that is not really a minimal sample we can easily check, have you tried to simply use `ancestor::PreciseIDServer/Header/ReferenceNumber` instead of trying to take all those `..` parent steps?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to rely on `ancestor` instead of trying to get the right parent level, that way you could also merge

```
<!-- Adding ReferenceNumber tag to ChangeOfAddressRcd -->
<xsl:template match="ChangeOfAddressRcd"> 
     <ChangeOfAddressRcd>
        <ReferenceNumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../../../../Header/ReferenceNumber"/>
        </ReferenceNumber>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </ChangeOfAddressRcd>                      
</xsl:template>

<!-- Adding ReferenceNumber tag to ConsumerIDRcd -->
<xsl:template match="ConsumerIDRcd"> 
    <ConsumerIDRcd>
        <ReferenceNumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../../../../Header/ReferenceNumber"/>
        </ReferenceNumber>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </ConsumerIDRcd>                      
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="ChangeOfAddressRcd | ConsumerIDRcd">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | ancestor::PreciseIDServer/Header/ReferenceNumber | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Perfect. That worked like a charm. Thank you so much Martin :)